# JAX-RS and Long Polling

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, long-polling, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to use long polling with JAX-RS (Jersey implementation) and it doesn't work as I expect. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. I would appreciate any advice.

Please note that using a reverse connection (something like Atmosphere, Comet, etc) is not a option for security reason. Not that I'm currently developing with Tomcat 7.

The following method is invoked from a JQuery Ajax call (using `$.ajax`).

```
@Path("/poll")
@GET
public void poll(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse)
        throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.asyncResponse = asyncResponse;
            // wait max. 30 seconds using a CountDownLatch
            latch.await(getTimeout(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The other method is invoked from my application (after a JMS call):

```
@POST
@Path("/printed")
public Response printCallback() {
    // ...

    // I expect the /poll call to be ended here from the client perspective but that is not the case
    asyncResponse.resume("UPDATE"); 
    latch.countDown();

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

If I remove the Thread creation in the `poll` method. Then it works, but the problem is that a Thread is busy. If I use the Thread creation, then the method is returning directly and the browser is not detecting the end of the long polling.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem. The problem was in the configuration. We must specify that the Jersey servlet supports `async` and then it works fine:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    ...
</servlet>
```

Please note that if you have Servlet filters, they also need to be `async-supported` to `true.`

This was also not necessary to create a thread. Jersey does it for me:

```
@Path("/poll")
@GET
public void poll(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse)
        throws InterruptedException {
    asyncResponse.setTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    this.asyncResponse = asyncResponse;
}

@POST
@Path("/printed")
public Response printCallback(String barcode) throws IOException {
    // ...

    this.asyncResponse.resume("MESSAGE");

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

When calling `poll` the browser waits until receiving `MESSAGE` or receiving a HTTP status 503 if the timeout is elapsed. In the server, the request thread is not blocked until the timeout but released directly. In the client side, I have a JavaScript which is calling the method again if the timeout occurs, otherwise I process something in the page.

Comment: How did you find that you don't need to create a thread explicitly? In the examples in the Jersey documentation they do create the thread: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html

Comment: I'v seen that. I assume this is a problem in the examples. Threads should not be created by the code itself, otherwise what is the advantage of the Async requests? Furthermore, that works without manual thread creation. If the 'async-supported' is supported to true, then the application server creates the Thread. I checked that using the debugger.

Comment: But aren't you missing the '@ManagedAsync' annotation in your poll method? see https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ManagedAsync.html

Comment: Or maybe the '@ManagedAsync' is just a more specific way (at method level) of telling Jersey that it must create a thread for the async method, instead of the <async-supported>true</async-supported> that works at servlet level

Comment: You are right. `@ManagedAsync` is Jersey specific. I usually prefer the standard way.